# Difficulty with boolean statement

Tags: python

Write a function named `same_side` that takes two integers as parameters. The function will return a Boolean which represents `True` if the inputs are both greater than 41 or if they are both less than 41. If the inputs are not on the same side of 41 or if either input is equal to 41 then the function should return a value representing `False`.

```
def same_side(x, y):
    if x > 41 and x < 41:
        return True
    if y > 41 and y < 41:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The input [14, 0] should make the statement true, but I am getting false.

Comment: What do you think `if x > 41 and x < 41` means?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm I think you are having trouble interpreting the question possibly?

if both `x` and `y` are greater than `41`

```
if x > 41 and y > 41
```

if both `x` and `y` are less than `41`

```
if x < 41 and y < 41
```

Your `else` statement is fine

Answer (score 1):

Please explain how you expect a single value of x to be less than 41 and greater than 41 *at the same time*. This would violate the **Law of Excluded Middle**.

Look at the words you used; turn *those* into `if` statements.  For instance:

```
if x > 41 and y > 41:
```

See the difference?

Now, to do this more succinctly ...

```
return (x > 41 and y > 41) or \
       (x < 41 and y < 41)
```

This will compute the desired Boolean value in one not-so-simple expression.  There's no `if`, no `else`.

Answer (score 0):

you mean this?

```
def same_side(x=14, y=0):
    if x > 41 and y > 41:
        return True
    elif x < 41 and y < 41:
        return True
    return False
```

And `Prune`'s answer is more briefly